# Button to open Jquery Dialog is not working

Tags: jquery-ui

I am playing with Jquery UI

I create a dialog on the fly from a DIV, i gave this DIV and ID and a button to call a closeDialog Function

It works fine as shown on this example

http://jsbin.com/ubovej

The problem I am having, is that if I d load a page THAT contains the BUTTON. The button will not work

as in:

```
$("<div id='mydialog1'>").dialog({ 
         autoOpen: false, 
         modal: false,
         width: 740, 
         height: 840,
         title: 'Dialog1 = dynamic',
         open: function(e, ui){   
            $(this).load(myUrl);  
         }                        
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the button?

Answer (score 2):

If this is the button Click Event code then

```
autoOpen: false,
```

should be

```
autoOpen: true,
```

EDIT: If you don't want it opened til you click the button then:

Do this when you want the dialog created.

```
var $dialog = $("<div id='mydialog1'>").dialog({ 
     autoOpen: false, 
     modal: false,
     width: 740, 
     height: 840,
     title: 'Dialog1 = dynamic',
     open: function(e, ui){   
        $(this).load(myUrl);  
     }                        
 });
```

and do this after they click the button (only after the dialog is created)

```
$("button_selector").click(function () {
    $dialog.dialog("open");
});
```

EDIT: Try changing

```
function closeDialog1(){                                                                                                                
   alert('closing Dialog1');                                                                                                            
   window.parent.$('#mydialog1').dialog('close');                                                                                                     
   return false;                                                                                                                        
}
```

to

```
function closeDialog1(){                                                                                                                
   alert('closing Dialog1');                                                                                                            
   $('#mydialog1').dialog('close');                                                                                                     
   return false;                                                                                                                        
}
```

Or a better way to do this might be

```
$("<div id='mydialog1'>").dialog({ 
         autoOpen: false, 
         modal: false,
         width: 740, 
         height: 840,
         title: 'Dialog1 = dynamic',
         open: function(e, ui){   
            $(this).load('dialogtest1a.html');  
         },
         buttons: {
             "Close" : function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
             }     
         }                   
});
```

Does the button that closes the dialog HAVE TO be in the page you are loading?

Comment: I don't want it opened till the click on link/button 
function showDialog1(){
   $('#mydialog1').dialog('open');
   return false;
}

Comment: Could you post the actual code that you are having problems with, not an example you worked off of?

Comment: this is the actual code on my testarea. i uploaded it to server. http://www.tanela.com/testbin/dialogtest1.html. The close button on the dialog is not working

Comment: and yes, i did want to have the close button(onclick) in the page that was being loaded.. :(

Comment: on my SECOND example here is the link :
http://www.tanela.com/testbin/dialogtest2.html 

Here I DO NOT create the dialog on the fly, and I use an Iframe. the close button WORKS on this example. But the Dialog is much SLOWER to load all my content

Comment: the button that is not on the loading page as u suggested is also failing:(
ALSO, once I close the dialog it will not reopen unless i refresh page