# How do i open an ajax loaded jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to open a jQuery UI dialog of which the HTML has been loaded by ajax, but I'm only getting the alert.

```
    $(document).on("click",'#dialog-button',function(){
        alert('this works');
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');//this doesn't
    });
```

When I put the html inside the template without using ajax (and .on), I experience no problems.

The dialog html is loaded by ajax like something simular to this:

```
$.ajax({

type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
url: href,

success: function(data){

$('#dialog-container').html(data.dialog);

}

});
```

And in my php i'll do something like this:

```
<?php 
 //assign some variables
 $array = array('dialog' => $this->smarty->fetch('dialog.tpl'));
 echo json_encode($array);
 ?>
```

This works:

```
$(document).on("click",'#dialog-button',function(){

    alert('this works');

    $('#dialog').dialog({

    autoOpen : true,
    height   : 500,
    width    : 1000,
    modal    : true,
    buttons  : {

        save  : function() {

            sendForm();
            $(this).dialog('close');

        },

        cancel : function() {

            $(this).dialog('close');

        },

        close    : function(){

            allFields.vall('').removeClass('ui-sate-error');

        },

    }

})

})
```

Comment: have you included jQuery Ui lib? and there seems an extra `});`.

Comment: i'm using google librarys

Answer (score 1):

After loading the dialog contents you need to actually create the dialog box:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#dialog-container').html(data.dialog);
    $('#dialog').dialog({
       ...,
       autoOpen: false
    });
},
```

and then the code you have above will actually make it appear:

```
$(document).on("click",'#dialog-button', function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

Make sure that `#dialog` is initially hidden otherwise the dialog's contents will appear on the page before they get turned into the dialog.

Comment: also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375352/button-to-open-jquery-dialog-is-not-working

Comment: I did what you said and first loaded the content, after that i created the dialog box. It doesn't seem to make any differance.

Comment: @user2157854 so please add to your question details about how you load the content - don't forget that'll be an async operation.

Comment: When i use just $('#dialog').dialog() i get the dialog, but it's missing buttons and it's smaller.

Comment: @user2157854 sure, you still have to supply the various options to configure the dialog.  But only once, when you create it, not when you open it.

Comment: no, you were supposed to move the main `.dialog({...})` call _outside_ of the click handler and only have `.dialog('open')` inside it.  See my updated answer.

Comment: This is the part where its failing. If i do it as updated in my topic it works, if i put the .dialog outside the click handler it's not working. Any ideas how this is possible?